# Is it efficient to use large scale data algorithms on disk?

Tags: bloom-filters, big-data

Is it efficient to use algorithms like locality sensitive hashing and bloom filters  on disk instead of memory for very large datasets where even these structures cannot be saved in memory?

Comment: Generally it is always less efficient to perform computations on *mass storage*.

Comment: The answer depends on the algorithm.